# Jquery parseJSON not getting value

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp

I am very new in cakephp and JSON. Here I am trying to fetch a list by ajax and trying to put it as a input value.

Here I am using cakephp.I get the product list by find method

```
$products = $this->Product->find('list',array(
                         'conditions' => array('Product.client_id'=>$client_id)
));
```

then I have written `json_encode` for encode list

```
echo json_encode($books);
```

Now in success message I have written

```
success: function(data)
{
    var products = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(products);
}
```

I found the alert message [object Object]. Now here how can I get the product list?

The output of `var_dump($products)`  look like below array

```
array(23){ 
   [8] => string(5) "apple" 
   [9] => string(6)  "orange"
   ---------------
   ---------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery each function:

try:

```
   success: function(data)
    {
        var products = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(products,function(i,v){
           alert(v);
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for:

```
for( var product in products )
      console.log(products[product]);
```

Prints:

```
apple
orange
...
```

Comment: Where I have to use this ?